# Can a Highcharts Polar chart have a logarithmic y-axis?

Tags: highcharts

I've been trying to create a highcharts polar chart that has a logarithmic y-axis, but when I add the axis type, the chart disappears.

Example without logarithmic:  http://jsfiddle.net/jbirdjavi/XPZhe/

Example with logarithmic:  http://jsfiddle.net/jbirdjavi/XPZhe/1/

```
yAxis: {
        type: 'logarithmic',
        min: 0,
        max: 20,
        endOnTick: false,
        showLastLabel: true,
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.value;
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible but with one limitation: `yAxis.min` have to be higher than 0, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/XPZhe/3/